# dropdown selected value wrong when the values are loaded through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 dropdowns, ddlYear and ddlMonth. Both dropdowns have the values loaded in ASP.Net C# during a page load. (Year is the fiscal year which starts from July to June. For 2014-2015 I need to show only July. for 2013-2014, the month list is July through June)
When the year is changed i am loading the months using jquery on client side.

```
 $('#ddlMonth').empty();
            $.each(data, function (index2, val) {
                $('#ddlMonth').append($('<option></option>').val(val.Key).html(val.Value));
            });
```

If I access the selected value using jquery $("#ddlMonth").val() it displays correct. However if I select the value from ASP.Net C# ddlMonth.SelectedValue it gives the wrong value/the initial default value.
Here's my c# code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
        ddlFiscalYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(fiscalYearStart.ToString() + "-" + (fiscalYearStart + 1).ToString(),       fiscalYearStart.ToString()));
                ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue = fiscalYearStart.ToString();
        var months = GetMonthsForFiscalYear(fiscalYearStart);
        foreach (DateTime month in months)
                {
                    if (month < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        ddlMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(month.ToString("MMMM"), month.Month.ToString()));
                    }
                }
        string defaultMonth = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
        ddlMonth.SelectedValue = defaultMonth;
}
}

  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Month = Int32.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
}
```

I am not able to figure out what is the mistake here...

Comment: `I am not able to figure out what is the mistake here.`  Neither can we without your asp.net code.  Show your page load and also show where you access ddlMonth.SelectedValue.

Comment: Added the asp.net code

Comment: @rkatta share your `.aspx` code, it might help...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option is to use a client side hidden field to store the selected item from the dropdown.  There is a disconnect between the client side data and server side data.

Use jQuery to populate this field when a new month is selected

```
<input id="hdnSelectedMonth" type="hidden" runat="server">
```

and in your code behind you can reference it:

```
Month = Int32.Parse(hdnSelectedMonth.Value);
```

Comment: Yeah my next thought was this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Rick. I marked it as answer. But I am still looking if someone could help me understand the causes for this. May be I am missing on some basics and would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to change the contents of a server side control using jquery.  The data in the server side control is also stored in ViewState and jquery can't update it, so you're going to have major issues when the server tries to read the input and make sense of it.

I would suggest you use a plain HTML control (no `runat="server"`) for the month, and read it server-side with something like

```
var month = Request["Month"];
```